# SQL Function DIFFERENCE returns interesting scores

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Can anyone explain why the SQL function (using SQL Server 2019) returns results that to me appear to be counter intuitive? Here are the queries and the scores:

```
SELECT 
    DIFFERENCE('Good', 'Good Samaritans'); --Result is 4 (High score match)

SELECT 
    DIFFERENCE('Samaritans', 'Good Samaritans'); --Result is 1 (Low score match)

SELECT 
    DIFFERENCE('Sam', 'Good Samaritans'); --Result is 2 (A higher score than above!)
```

I understand `DIFFERENCE` uses `SOUNDEX` to match consonants phonetically, but the results above seem very odd particularly with the second query. Is it something to do with the space and the proceeding string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the order of words you will see there is a bias on the first word. Then if you consider [SOUNDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) you will begin to understand why. Also read the reference below.

> SOUNDEX converts an alphanumeric string to a four-character code that is based on how the string sounds when spoken in English. The
> first character of the code is the first character of
> character_expression, converted to upper case. The second through
> fourth characters of the code are numbers that represent the letters
> in the expression. The letters A, E, I, O, U, H, W, and Y are ignored
> unless they are the first letter of the string. Zeroes are added at
> the end if necessary to produce a four-character code. For more
> information about the SOUNDEX code, see [The Soundex Indexing
> System](https://www.archives.gov/research/census/soundex)

```
-- Bias based on left to right order of words
SELECT 10 id, DIFFERENCE('Good', 'Good Samaritans') --Result is 4 (High score match)
union all
SELECT 11 id, DIFFERENCE('Good', 'Samaritans Good') --Result is 1 (Low score match)
union all
SELECT 20, DIFFERENCE('Samaritans', 'Good Samaritans') --Result is 1 (Low score match)
union all
SELECT 21, DIFFERENCE('Samaritans', 'Samaritans Good') --Result is 4 (High score match)
union all
SELECT 30, DIFFERENCE('Sam', 'Good Samaritans') --Result is 2 (On the upper low side)
```

| id | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 4 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 20 | 1 |
| 21 | 4 |
| 30 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MLNIREfi)

Your expectations from `difference` may be too high.

Comment: Great answer @Paul Maxwell. The bias on the first word makes sense and you're probably correct with my expectations. A possible way to make it work with strings with multiple words might be to split the strings and evaluate each word, then put it all together to work out a final score... messy!

Comment: I thought the same, splitting by word and determine an overall result. You may want to strip out stop words such as 'as' 'and' 'the' etc. Sounds like an interesting project :-)